# No boot, no bios after Reformat, Dual Boot install

Tags: boot, bios

PC needed reformat so completed this with just after installing Ubuntu onto my 2nd drive and had Dual boot Win7 and Ubuntu 12.04 going fine (Except slow Win, hence reformat).  Reformated, reinstalled Win7.  Updated all drivers and installed critical software in Windows.  Once Win7 stable, installed Ubuntu 12.04 on 2nd Drive.  I chose top option in the install and let it complete some sort of partition (Although I see no other drive in Win).

So now when I start the PC after the install completed, it went straight to the Win7 login screen.  I attempted to put the Ubuntu install disk in and it did start Ubuntu after attempting to install and finding I already had a version.  But this was not satifying enough for me.  So I researched and found a tool, boot-repair disk.  When I launch this, it basically takes me to a BOOT: terminal looking screen, but I am lost from what errors it was giving (Sorry, don't have).

I am a relative novice when it comes to Ubuntu, but I know how great it is.  But this is frustrating that the simple boot menu is not working.  I am not sure even the best way to even start Ubuntu (Very slow using install disk) to try some other solutions.

Any direction is appreciated.  BTW, no bios options either anymore.  This was a change since the install of 12.04

Answer (score 1):

BIOS can't be controlled by OS. BIOS is the thing that loads OS. Check your manufacture manual to get into BIOS. Maybe your screen is starting late. Keep on pressing `F2` or `Del` (as per manufacture instruction) after powering it on.

Please follow guide below to repair the boot. (It might be the same application you are using as boot-repair disk)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair (Use `recomended repair`)

If it doesn't work, run the tool again and click on `Create bootinfo summery`. It will give you a url. Please post that url here.

Comment: Well to be fair, there are software out there that is run at the OS level, but is able to change the BIOS after a reboot. Say, a ThinkPad BIOS Update Utility :)

Comment: No,there is space in BIOS where can put the payload (or the utility can instruct BIOS to load the payload from a specific location). The utility puts the payload at that point, restarts the system. BIOS update section detects there is a update for BIOS core & it flashes  for the core. And I am sure definitely there is no OS who does that, a update software does.

Comment: That's true but you're insinuating that it's impossible to mess with the BIOS from the OS. Which isn't true! Thanks for the explanation though!